# Telethon italic formatting doesn't work at the last item of list

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am building a mention bot for telegram groups with Telethon library. I want to mention all administrators of group in italic format. But it doesn't make italic the last line.

```
async def tag(event):
    chat_from = event.chat if event.chat else (await event.get_chat())
    admin_list = await botsaztagger.get_participants(chat_from, filter=ChannelParticipantsAdmins)
    admins = ''

    for i in range(len(admin_list)):
        user = admin_list[i]
        if user.deleted or user.bot:
            pass
        else:
            name = user.first_name
            if user.last_name:
                name += ' ' + user.last_name

            admins += ' __[{}](tg://user?id={})__\n'.format(name.strip(), user.id)

    message = """**{}** List of administrators:

{}""".format(chat_from.title, admins)
    await event.respond(message)
    print(message)
```

If you look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdqk3.png), you can see some of the names are not italic. I printed the message in the console to see if there is something wrong, but everything looks okay

```
**YeTeam** List of administrators:

 __[Tamerlan](tg://user?id=731644382)__
 __[Shahin Bv](tg://user?id=753855865)__
 __[Samed Jabbarov](tg://user?id=807246109)__
 __[Haji Jafarli](tg://user?id=850522538)__
 __[Vüqar Stanbullu](tg://user?id=603068273)__
 __[Tuqay](tg://user?id=812891027)__
 __[Star Dust](tg://user?id=887740534)__
 __[Darth Nihilus](tg://user?id=841608283)__
 __[Taleh Əfəndi](tg://user?id=764835170)__
 __[Fariz](tg://user?id=649855510)__
```

How can I fix it? What am I missing?

Comment: I think telegram has a limit on entities in one message (around 20ish)

Comment: If you use `telethon.extensions.markdown.parse(message text)`, you can see that the mentions and italics are parsed correctly. The Telegram server probably doesn't support italic mentions. I believe the limit is 100 entities but only 20 mentions too.

Comment: Maybe the server does support them, not sure, you could try with raw API `SendMessageRequest`; if it still happens then after all offsets are correct please open a bug report.